# C++ implicit cast - How to force a warning

Tags: c++, g++, implicit-conversion

I am following a C++ training and I found out a behavior I find weird in C++ when learning about `explicit` keyword.

About the following snippet, it will compile and execute without any error or warning (compile with G++).

When calling `Foo(5)`, it will automatically do an implicit conversion and actually call `Foo(A(5))`.

I know I can forbid this behavior by making the constructor of `A` explicit : `explicit A(int a);` but my question is :

- **Is there a way to make G++ warn about implicit conversion like that if I forgot to do so?**

I tried g++ with `-Wall -Wextra`, I saw stuff on `-Wconversion` on SO but still build without any warnings.

Looking on the internet I found out some warnings seem to exist for C and ObjC, but not for C++...

[image]

Source: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

***The snippet:***

```
#include <iostream>

class A{
    public:
        A(int a) 
        {
            m_a = a;
        };

        int m_a;
};

void Foo(A a)
{
    std::cout << "Hello : " << a.m_a << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Foo(5);  // No Warning ?
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

> Hello : 5

Comment: You have the option of making the ctor `explicit` so why do you want compiler warning? The fact that you didn't make the ctor explicit implies that you want implicit conversions. **You can't have it both ways**.

Comment: Short answer: No.  You have a converting constructor, so the compiler isn't going to warn you about conversions.

Comment: @JasonLiam I just learnt about 'explicit' and to me it was an obvious behavior. Now I realize that for code protection I should make all my CTORs explicit to avoid this, which I find a bit cumberstone

Comment: @PierreBaret C++ gives you the ability to choose for yourself whether you want an `int` to be converted to `Foo`. And you have to be explicit about it. When you write a non-explicit converting ctor, you're saying that you want an implicit conversion from `int` to `Foo` allowed. So you've made that choice. If you don't want this then make the ctor `explicit`. **You pay for what you use**.

Comment: @NathanOliver so it is called "converting constructor", thanks for the hint, I found more about this : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor

Comment: It is unfortunate that `explicit` isn't the default. But in many cases an implicit conversion is also intended. A compiler warning for every use of a converting constructor would give you way too many false positives which could also not be silenced except by a compiler-specific suppression.

Comment: Can't confirm, but I believe you can check for this with clang-tidy to get warnings about non-explicit converting constructors.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, there is a check in clang-tidy for this based on the Google coding guidelines, see https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/google/explicit-constructor.html, but following that guideline will make a lot of code will requiring writing a lot of code more verbose than usual.

Comment: There is no such thing as an implicit cast. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion; it is always explicit. The term you're looking for is **implicit conversion**.

Comment: @PeteBecker My bad for the bad turn of phrase, I actually put the correct one in the tags of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to make G++ warn about implicit casts like that if I forgot to do so?

No, the fact that you have a choosen to have a non-explicit conversion constructor says that you want implicit conversion from `int` to `Foo` allowed.

If that is not desirable, then you always have the option of making this converting ctor `explicit` to forbid this completely. No way to have it both ways.

---

> Now I realize that for code protection I should make all my CTORs explicit to avoid this, which I find a bit cumberstone

**You pay for what you use**.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I don't mind paying when I understand ;-)